# Whats the purpose : Hilbert's problems in measure space

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I've got an assignment to consider boundary problems in space of finite measures ***W***, where the boundary conditions are considered in sense of weak approximation.

For example Hilbert's problem with boundary condition in sense of weak approx. will have following definition. 
$$
\lim_{r \to 1-0}\int\limits_T \ ({\Phi^+(rt)}-a(t){\Phi^-(r^{-1}t)})g(t)dt=\int\limits_Tg(t)d\mu 
$$
Where 
$$ 
T = \{ z: |z|=1 \},\ \forall g \in C,\ d\mu \in W \\\Phi^+(z)\ - \text{analytic function inside unit circle}\\ 
\Phi^-(z)\ -\text{analytical function outside the unit circle}\\
a(t) - \text{is a piecewise continuous function from Hölder's space.}
$$

Questions :

- I would like to understand what is the idea of formulating the
  problem in measure space ?
- What generalization it does ?

Comment: I guess the idea is that we look for a measure that is the weak limit of something related to the limit of the integrand on the left as $r\to 1$. But much remains unclear here. For example, how is $g$ related to $a$, if at all? Generally, what are the quantifiers here: the equation must hold *for  some ...*, *for all ... such that ...*, etc.

Comment: just updated the question, $$ a(t) - is\ a\ piecewise\ continues\ function\ from\ Hölder's\ space $$ and $$ g - is\ any\ function\ from\ C $$

Comment: This is better but I still want a clarification about $r$. There is no $r$ on the right. Should there be $\lim\limits_{r\to 1}$ on the left?

Comment: Correct, sorry for non-full info.